# Django self.cleaned_data not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm new to the technology, so I apologyze in advance if the question is too simple.

I'm using self.cleaned_data to get the selected data entered by the user. And it works when clean is called, but not on my save method.

Here is the code

Forms.py

```
def clean_account_type(self):
    if self.cleaned_data["account_type"] == "select": # **here it works**
        raise forms.ValidationError("Select account type.")

def save(self):
    acc_type = self.cleaned_data["account_type"] # **here it doesn't, (NONE)**

    if acc_type == "test1":
        doSomeStuff()
```

Any ideas why that's not working when I call save?

Here is my views.py

```
def SignUp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `clean_<field_name` methods on the form *must* return the clean value or raise a `ValidationError`. From the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/

> Just like the general field clean() method, above, this method should
>   return the cleaned data, regardless of whether it changed anything or
>   not.

The simple change would be

```
def clean_account_type(self):
    account_type = self.cleaned_data["account_type"]
    if account_type == "select":
        raise forms.ValidationError("Select account type.")
    return account_type
```